# Updating ios app do I increment both the build number or just the version?

Tags: ios

I am about to update my app for the first time. I am in xcode and looking at the project targets. My new version number is 1.0.1 so do I just change my version number here? Do I need to increment the build number too?

Comment: Yes, you must update the build number every time you submit a binary. The version only needs to be updated once per update the user will see.

Comment: so I need to set both version to 1.0.1 and Build to 1.0.1?

Comment: They don't have to be the same. If the build is rejected you need to fix it, update the build number again (but not the version number) and upload the new build.

Comment: oh, so setting 2 (as it's my second ever binary upload) is more appropriate? Do I need to fiddle with anything in the Info.plist too?

Comment: The build number is associated with version number. So there is no need to change build number when changing version number.

Comment: @Satachito Sorry but that is incorrect. The build number must be incremented every time you submit the binary. The version number only needs to be updated once per version (as seen by the user).

Comment: The [following search](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=CFBundleVersion+CFBundleShortVersionString) shows many discussions on what to use for the version and build values.

Answer (score 4):

The build number should really be increased by 1 every time you check in a new version into git. Build number shouldn't be 1.0.1, it should be for example 3915 (if you checked in 3915 changes into git). It's a sequential number.

If you have released 1.0.1 and want to release 1.0.2, you send the next build number and version 1.0.2 to Apple. If it is rejected, you make changes, increase the build number, and leave the version at 1.0.2. If your version is accepted, and downloaded by end users, the next time you send an upgrade to Apple it should have version 1.0.3 and again the next build number.

Comment: Understand now thanks. Do I need to change anything in the Info.plist too?